# It is possible to create checkbox inside combo box

Tags: javascript, html

checkbox inside combo box using html and javascript is possible? I have tried it doesn't works..

Comment: @jleedev, Combo box = <select> element

Comment: A combo box is a drop down list.

Comment: not without emulating a combobox (dropdown) using javascript, so you can have arbitrary content as list items

Comment: You mean somethin linke this? http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: In terms of usability, it seems the regular `select` element with the `multiple` attribute set would do pretty much the same thing; although it'd be visually different, obviously. And possibly slightly clumsier to use...

Comment: @david but i want a checkbox inside select not select to choose multiple attribute thanks for understanding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain HTML does not allow check boxes inside `<select>` elements.

However, depending on your requirements, you might be interested in [this jQuery UI plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't put put check boxes into combo boxes. If you want the user to be able to select multiple items, I suggest you make a list of check boxes instead.

Comment: if more values how it is posible

Comment: @balz I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @balz, I still don't think I understand. Are you asking on how to limit the size of the list that is displayed on the page?

Comment: what it means exactly    **you make a list of check boxes instead**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select box, and define its `size`, and set `multiple=multiple`.

```
<select size="7" name="sports" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Football</option>
    <option>Baseball</option>
</select>
```

That way, you'll have a list of items, and you can select multiple ones.